# is it possible to get the lost data deleted from rails console?

Tags: mysql

The command I ran in rails console is

`Product.delete_all("id > 44 AND id < 51")`

Is there any way to get the records back?

Thanks

Comment: No.. the command you used did the _commit_ .. But Umm.. A DBA can help you it seems..

Comment: If you have an sql log, or log the sql into your regular log, you can grep the log for insert and update statements for the record in question.  If this is your production environment, you should be doing database backups on a regular basis.  Now's the time to start, if you aren't.

Comment: If this is rails console then check the logs.